# Loving Meryl Streep

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

The answer to this riddle is a single word.

> Murray Abraham as Greek.
>   The sun seen from the dark side.
>   And someone who is always late.
>
> The whole?
>   I just love Meryl Streep!

Comment: Thought on this one for a while. Let's see if anything comes to mind. Might need a hint added tho.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the word is

> PHILOSOPHY

Argument:

> * PHI = Greek letter F = **F.** Murray Abraham
>  * LOS = SOL backwards = sun seen from the dark side
>  * OPHY = someone who is always late; http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ophy

And:

> * PHILOS $\approx$ philia,  Greek word for "Love"; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_words_for_love
>  * SOPHY = Meryl Streep's role in "Sophie's Choice" (Thanks to  @KeyboardWielder)

Comment: I'm still not convinced on the term that only has one urbandictionary definition to support it, but I like this one a lot otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

I think the word is:

> sophy / Sophie

Because:

> loving = -sophy
>  Meryl Streep = Sophie in "Sophie's Choice"

I'm not sure of the rest, but some Googling suggests:-

> sophy (wise man)
>  Sophie Harrison
>  Sophie Foster

I don't know if Googling was in the right spirit of answering this puzzle, so for now I'll leave it there and perhaps let someone else post a better answer...

Answer (score 2):

I think the word is

> Oscar

This part is incomplete:

> Murray Abraham as Greek - refers to F Murray Abraham's role in Mighty Aphrodite
>  The sun seen from the dark side - Dark Side of the Sun, Brad Pitt's first leading role.
>  And someone who is always late - could refer to how Oscar bait movies are usually released very late in the year, so as to be fresh in Oscar voters' minds.
>  I just love Meryl Steep! - Holds records for the most nominations (including 3 wins)

Comment: But these connections to the Oscar are rather vague. F Murray Abraham did not receive an Oscar for his role in Mighty Aphrodite, just the movie itself did receive an Oscar. If you find the real answer, then every line will make sense.